# Get value out of html tag (tinymce 4.x)

Tags: html, tags, tinymce-4

I'm trying to get the first font-family out of tinymce editor content (HTML). F.e.:

```
<p><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Find font here</span></p>
```

I would like to get back "arial, helvetica, sans-serif;"

After some research I found a [parser from tinymce](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce.dom/tinymce.dom.domquery/) itself, probably doing something like this:

```
tinymce.dom.DomQuery('p').attr('span', 'font-family').find('font-family'));
```

What you see is my already interpreted search option but nothing will returned. I also have JQuery if this is a (better) option. What I want (first font-family in whole text) is probably pretty simple, I just don't get it how...

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to achieve using jQuery's css method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var span = $('p span').first();
  var fontFam = span.css('font-family');
  $('p').append('<pre>'+fontFam+'</pre>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Find font here</span></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't know how to transform that to my project. Your solution relies on the page where the HTML is. As I said, I'm working with tinymce. I might have my HTML text to be parsed in a variable. I don't see how I can replace/add that to your shown selection 'p span'.